# What to do when a selector doesn't show the expected text?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have the following html file.

```
<tr> 
  <th class = 'class1'> </th>
  <td class = 'price' id = 'cell-1234'>$100</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to get the text of the class 'price' using CasperJS. I can't use the id because it keeps changing with every iteration.

Using the below code I get a blank line. I am not sure which function would get me the text.

```
casper.then(function(){
    console.log(this.fetchText('.price'));
});
```

What can I do to find the error?

Comment: Checked that. There is just one. Is there way to inject jquery into this script. I tried a bunch of ways, all giving an error.

Comment: I hope it is ok that I used your question to make it a little broader. Let's clean up the comments.

Comment: Sure. Mine was solved by waiting for a bit till the value is displayed.

Comment: AJAX -> wait() >> then().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML looks fine and the selector should match. There are multiple things that you should do:

- Check that you are on the correct page, for example by printing `casper.getTitle()`.
- Check that the element that you want to select actually exists in the page. This is particularly relevant for Single Page Apps or simple AJAX enhanced web apps. This can be done by either printing the whole page content `casper.getHTML()` or only a small portion of the page `casper.getHTML("div.something")` which contains the element in question. To fix this, you can use `casper.wait*`.
- Check that the element that you want to select can actually be in the page. Sometimes web sites deliver different pages based on user agent string and change layout due to viewport size (default for PhantomJS is ~400x320). You should keep that in mind when writing selectors based on desktop browsers.